# Why aren't my before_validation methods firing if some validation is scoped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, callback

In my model I've got a couple of methods to populate attributes of an `Invoice` before it is validated:

```
validates :account_id, :presence => true
validates :account_address, :presence => true
validates :number, :presence => true
validates :number, :uniqueness => true, :scope => :client_id

before_validation :generate_number, :associate_addresses, :on => :create

def generate_number
  self.number = self.client.invoices.count + 1
end

def associate_addresses
  self.account_address = self.account.addresses.first
end
```

And in the controller:

```
@invoice = @account.invoices.build(:client_id => @client.id)

if @invoice.save
  #it saved
end
```

My problem is that the `associate_addresses` and `generate_number` methods only fire if I remove the `:scope => :client_id` argument on the `:number` validation.

Why would it skip the `before_validation` callbacks due to this?

Working in Rails 3.0.3

Thanks!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why it's skipping the `before_validation` methods, but to scope a `uniqueness` validation in Rails 3 you should use the following syntax:

```
validates :number, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :scope => :client_id }
```

I guess that your syntax is making it try to add a `scope` validation, which doesn't exist. Probably there's a Rails bug that makes that skip the `before_validation` methods.

Comment: I seem to be having a similar problem. The validations appear valid but totally invalid data passes, and .valid? always returns true. Do you have any idea where to start looking for what's causing this to happen?